# Flutter- Is there an option to get the text of websites in my flutter mobile app?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

Im sorry, Ive been working with flutter from 3 months and this is the first time i had to come accross website and my app. I know that we can load webpages inside our app, and also we can load http data to our app. But when using http, we can only use websites of jsonplaceholder types. Am i right?

But I want to load simple websites text into my app, is that possible without jsonplaceholder? I want to access its body and use it as texts in multiple parts of my code. Is that really possible or should i hardcode it ? Can I find some Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using [Webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) for that?

In CMSs like Joomla, you can use &tmpl=component to show the inside of the webpage body. I think that the other CMSs have the same option.

For example:

```
yourwebsite/index.php?option=com_ebarge&view=ebuserschoolinfo&layout=edit&tmpl=component
```

You can embed your link like above in your Webview.

*Edit according to comments:*

For setting appBar heading as webpage header or something like that, there is no other way without using the Webview widget inside other widgets. For example, you can add your Webview inside Scaffold so you can set your custom AppBar on top of Webview. With initialHeaders of Webview, you can communicate with your webpage.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer @wahid anvary , but that is not what really i want, I dont want webview to be displayed. I want web content to be displayed on my app in customized widgets. Eg: setting appBar heading as webPage header. Is there a way?

Comment: If you can, please share your sample code. There is no other way without using the Webview widget inside other widgets. For example, you can add your Webview inside Scaffold so you can set your custom AppBar on top of Webview. With initialHeaders of Webview, you can communicate with your webpage.